# How can I require MongoDB within CasperJS?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, npm, casperjs

I am trying to insert records to a MongoDB collection from within CasperJS, but at the first hurdle I am blocked.

I first installed mongodb by running the following command in the root of my application:

```
npm install mongodb
```

This completes successfully without any errors.

I have a CasperJS file called server.js, which contains this line:

```
var db = require('mongodb');
```

When I try to run `casperjs server.js` with this, I get the following error:

```
js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version
Error: Cannot find module 'util'                                                
  /home/aaron/Documents/git/mateserver/phantomjs:/bootstrap.js:289
  /home/aaron/Documents/git/mateserver/phantomjs:/bootstrap.js:254 in require
  /home/aaron/Documents/git/mateserver/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/commands/insert_command.js:2
  /home/aaron/Documents/git/mateserver/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/commands/insert_command.js:162
```

Seems like I am missing a package, so I run the command:

```
npm install util
```

Which runs successfully, so I try to start my application again but get this error:

```
js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'inherits(InsertCommand, BaseCommand)')
  /home/aaron/Documents/git/mateserver/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/commands/insert_command.js:38
  /home/aaron/Documents/git/mateserver/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/commands/insert_command.js:162
```

And this is where I am stuck. How can I work around this? Is MongoDB not compatible with CasperJS?

I am using CasperJS version 1.1.0-beta3 with MongoDB (installed via npm) version 1.4.7. The host system is Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CasperJS runs on phantomjs which has similar, but distinct standard modules from node.js. You would need to look into all `require`'d modules inside of the mongodb module and rewrite them to use the [phantomjs API](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/API-Reference) instead of the [node.js API](http://nodejs.org/api/). You will probably run into some unsolvable issues.

In case of the `inherits` function, it seems like there is a cyclic dependency on the internal node.js `util` module that cannot be resolved. You may be able to resolve this by overwriting `inherits.js` with `inherits_browser.js` in `node_modules/util/node_modules/inherits`.

Comment: Thanks. It sounds like it could be more effort than it is worth. Perhaps it would be more worth my time to reprogram what I have in CasperJS in to SpookyJS, or even make some custom wrapper for some Selenium webdriver controller.

Comment: You can spawn (or use child_process) a casper instance from node, write the results into a file, read that file from node and save into mongodb.

Comment: @ArtjomB. : The solution that you just said here. Will that work?

Comment: @SameerSawla Yes, it will work. The node script only has to read the temporary file name from the call parameter. You should try it. If you have problems, [ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: Thanks again for this solution. Although it works well, I decided to start again using pure Node and selenium-webdriver. CasperJS gives some nice syntactic sugar but I feel like I'm limiting the potential of my app when I use it.

Comment: @ArtjomB. : Thanks buddy! It worked for me the way I wanted it to.

Answer (score 0):

You can look into SpookyJS as it drives CasperJS from NodeJS